# Not sure where these syntax errors are coming from

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flash-builder

I'm making a game using ActionScript 3.0 and the 2D game library FlashPunk.

I can't compile my program without getting these errors:

```
1086 Syntax Error: expecting semicolon before name.
1093 Syntax Error
1093 Syntax Error
1093 Syntax Error
```

Here's a screenshot showing them in Flash Builder:

[image]

All the files check out OK.  None of them have little red X's to imply that's where the error is coming from.  I really don't know where these errors are or how to debug them.

Anyone know how to debug this?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's weird is there are line numbers for the errors but no path to to a file under 'Path' (see the screenshot).  Also, in the Problems panel to the right, all of the errors under 'Type' say 'Flex Problem', but the code is all ActionScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like you have any syntax errors in your code.

But:  If you copied and pasted any code from the internet, or from a Word document, or from a TextField in the Flash IDE, or if this class was written on a Windows system and you're editing on the Mac, or if anything similar is true, you might have problems with invisible `null` characters.  Try to search for `\x00` (check regular expressions) and replace-all with an empty string.

If nothing else helps, re-type your entire class from scratch - invisible stuff might still be in there.

Edit:

To clarify: The invisible null character is read as an EOF (end-of-file) and this causes your compilation to fail. This is also why the error codes seem to make no sense.

I get these errors every time I paste text copied from TextFields in the Flash IDE, no matter what the text and/or font formatting is.

Comment: Thanks! I found the problem with your advice.  Turned out to be an XML file that I was trying to embed into part of the project. I wrote the file by hand in TextMate, but I guess there was something weird about the way I formatted it.

Answer (score 0):

Don't you need to give the package a name?

e.g.

```
package asdata {
 .. your code...
}
```

Comment: You don't need to name the package if it's in the same folder as the root.

Comment: No you don't. `package {}` is the default package.  Perfectly alright.